# Continuity of the function $\mathbb{R}^k \to\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto \ln(1+ \lVert x \rVert)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Examine the continuity of the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$
defined by $f(x) = \ln (1+ \lVert x \rVert)$, where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is a norm.

Comment: Please for a better format of writing please check this  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Answer (score 3):

It's the composition of continuous functions $x\mapsto \|x\|$, $x\mapsto x+1$, $x\mapsto \ln x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$; if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$|f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$ iff $\log ( 1+ |c|) - \varepsilon < \log(1+|x|) < \log(1+ |c|) + \varepsilon$, which holds iff
$$
\frac{1+|c|}{e^{\varepsilon}} - 1 - |c| < |x| - |c| < (1+|c|)e^{\varepsilon} - 1- |c|;
$$
this is implied by
$$
\big| |x| - |c| \big| < \min \bigg\{ \bigg| \frac{1+|c|}{e^{\varepsilon}} - 1 - |c| \bigg|, (1 + |c|)e^{\varepsilon} - 1 - |c| \bigg\} =: \delta;
$$
so if $|x-c| < \delta$, then $| |x| - |c|| \leq |x-c| < \delta$, whence $|f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Welcome any comments!